# Ignore everything except specific file-types and one file with a specific name

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder of this form:

```
├── .gitignore
│
├── a
│   ├── query.sql
│   ├── script.py
│
├── b
│   ├── query.sql
│   ├── excel.xlxs
│
├── c
│   ├── query.sql
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── deck.ppt
```

I want git to ignore everything except for the .sql files and the .gitignore at the root **only** (so not the .gitignore in folder c).

I tried

```
# Ignore everything ...
*

# ... except gitignore and SQL files ...
!.gitignore
!*.sql

# ... from all directories and subdirectories
!*/
```

but it doesn't ignore the .gitignore in folder c. How can I fix this? In reality, I have many more folders and in them .gitignore files that I want to ignore.

Comment: It doesn't ignore the `c/.gitignore` because of the rule `!.gitignore` in the top-level `.gitignore`. Do you want to unignore only the top-level `.gitignore` and ignore all other `.gitignore`?

Comment: @phd yes, this is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Add `/` to the rule `!.gitignore` so that the rule only works for the top-level directory:

```
!/.gitignore
```